# How to make a simple slideshow in JS?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a simple slideshow with JavaScript.

Here is my index.html

```
<body>
    <h1>Slideshow example</h1>
    <button onclick="slideshow.timer()">Next slide</button>
    <div id="container"></div>
 <script src="slide.js"></script>
</body>
```

And here is slide.js

```
var slideshow = {
    sliderImages: ["img/img1.png", "img/img2.png"],
    timer: function() { 
        this.sliderImages.forEach(function(img) {
            var container = document.getElementById('container');
            var image = document.createElement('img');
            container.appendChild(image);
            image.src= img;
        })
    }
}
```

If I click the "next slide" button, I see both of the images. It loops through the whole array. How could I make it loop through the array just once, when clicking the button?

I tried adding container.innerHTML = ''; so that the previous image would be removed when adding the next image, but that resulted it showing immidietly the image in sliderImages[1]. Am I approaching this whole thing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your code.  It is not the best way to write it but I just modified your example to show you the problem.  The problem is your timer function which is just going through all the elements in the array at once.  Instead what you may want to do is add some delay.

```js
var slideshow = {
    sliderImages: ["img/img1.png", "img/img2.png"],
    currentImgIndex: 0,
    timer: function() { 
      if (this.currentImgIndex < this.sliderImages.length ) {
        var image = document.getElementById('img');
        image.src= this.sliderImages[this.currentImgIndex];
        this.currentImgIndex++;
        setTimeout(function (){ slideshow.timer()}, 2000)
      } else {
        alert("no more images");
      }
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Slideshow example</h1>
    <img id="img"/>
    <button onclick="slideshow.timer()">Next slide</button>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="slide.js"> </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to change the images only when the button is clicked, you don't need the forEach loop. If you are going to change images without user interaction then you need the loop but you need setInterval also.